The line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$ over $\mathbf{CP}^{1}$
$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}\newcommand{\Proj}{\mathbf{P}}\newcommand{\Sheaf}{\mathcal{O}}$Note to posterity: This question got asked and deleted. As suggested in meta I'm reposting and including the deleted answer.

The book A Beginner's Guide to Holomorphic Manifolds (pp. 34 ff.) introduces holomorphic line bundles over the complex projective line by explicit trivialization:

The holomorphic line bundle of degree $k \in \mathbf{Z}$ over $\Proj^{1}$ is constructed explicitly as follows. Using the standard atlas, take two "trivial" families over $U_{0}$ and $U_{1}$ with coordinates $(z^{0}, \zeta^{0})$ and $(z^{1}, \zeta^{1})$—$z^{i}$ is the base coordinate and $\zeta^{i}$ is the fibre coordinate over $U_{i}$—and "glue them together" over the set $\Cpx^{\times} = \Proj^{1} \setminus \{0, \infty\}$ by the identification
$$
z^{0} = \frac{1}{z^{1}},\qquad
\zeta^{0} = \frac{\zeta^{1}}{(z^{1})^{k}}.
$$
This line bundle is usually denoted $\Sheaf_{\Proj^{1}}(k)$, or simply $\Sheaf(k)$ for brevity.

Exercise 3.6: Let $[Z^{0} : Z^{1} : Z^{2}]$ be homogeneous coordinates on $\Proj^{2}$. The projection map $p:[Z^{0} : Z^{1} : Z^{2}] \mapsto [Z^{0}: Z^{1}: 0]$ is defined everywhere except at the point $[0 : 0 : 1]$, and the image is the $\Proj^{1}$ in $\Proj^{2}$ with equation $Z^{2} = 0$. Let $H = \Proj^{2} \setminus [0 : 0 : 1]$. Show that $p:H \to \Proj^{1}$ is a holomorphic line bundle, and find the corresponding value of $k$. Show that the space of holomorphic sections is the set of linear functions $\{a_{0} Z^{0} + a_{1} Z^{1} \mid a_{i} \in \Cpx\}$.
Questions: How should we visualize the total space and projection map of $H$? How do we show $H$ is a holomorphic line bundle, and how is the space of sections of $H$ identified with the space of linear functions $\{a_{0} Z^{0} + a_{1} Z^{1} \mid a_{i} \in \Cpx\}$?

The geometric picture is Cartesian three-space with projection along the third axis. The third axis itself maps to $(0, 0, 0)$. Since this does not represent a point of the projective plane, projection is not defined on the third axis. But as a point of projective space, the third axis is $[0 : 0 : 1]$. Algebraic geometers know this as projecting away from a point to a projective hyperplane.
To find the degree of $H$, we can look at a trivializing cover:

In the set $U_{0}$ where $Z^{1} \neq 0$, we have affine coordinate $z^{0} = Z^{0}/Z^{1}$. Since
$$
[Z^{0} : Z^{1} : Z^{2}] = [Z^{0}/Z^{1} : 1 : Z^{2}/Z^{1}] = [z^{0} : 1 : Z^{2}/Z^{1}],
$$
we may take fibre coordinate $\zeta^{0} = Z^{2}/Z^{1}$.
In the set $U_{1}$ where $Z^{0} \neq 0$, we have affine coordinate $z^{1} = Z^{1}/Z^{0} = 1/z^{0}$ and fibre coordinate $\zeta^{1} = Z^{2}/Z^{0}$.

In the intersection $U_{0} \cap U_{1}$ (where $Z^{0}$ and $Z^{1}$ are both non-zero), we have
$$
\zeta^{0} = \frac{Z^{2}}{Z^{1}} = \frac{Z^{2}/Z^{0}}{Z^{1}/Z^{0}} = \frac{\zeta^{1}}{z^{1}},
$$
from which we read off $k = 1$.
A fairly standard argument to find the space of sections (that generalizes to arbitrary integers $k$, and may be found in Wells' Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds, and surely elsewhere) is to write a holomorphic section as a pair of entire functions $f_{0}$ in $U_{0}$ and $f_{1}$ in $U_{1}$ satisfying
$$
f_{1}(z^{1}) = g_{01}(z^{0}) f_{0}(z^{0}) = \frac{f_{0}(z^{0})}{z^{0}},
$$
or more simply, $f_{1}(1/z) = f_{0}(z)/z$.
Expand $f_{1}(w) = a_{0} + a_{1}w + a_{2}w^{2} + \cdots$ as a power series. Set $w = 1/z$ and equate coefficients in the transition formula. Qualitatively, the left-hand side has only terms of non-positive degree, while the right-hand side has only terms of degree at least $-1$. There are two "overlapping" degrees, so each section is identified with a graph
$$
Z^{2}/Z^{0} = \zeta^{1} = f(w) = a_{0} + a_{1}w = a_{0} + a_{1}Z^{1}/Z^{0},
$$
i.e., a linear function $Z^{2} = a_{1}Z^{0} + a_{1}Z^{1}$.
Finally, here is a geometric, after-the-fact way to see that linear expressions in homogeneous coordinates are sections of this bundle: Since the total space is a punctured projective plane, the image of a section is a projective line not passing through $[0 : 0 : 1]$, i.e., the graph of a linear function $Z^{2} = a_{0}Z^{0} + a_{1}Z^{1}$. Inversely, any such projective line maps bijectively to the projective line $Z^{2} = 0$ under projection, so is the image of a section.
